# How to avoid a mine being hit first in a tkinter version of minesweeper?

Tags: python, tkinter, minesweeper

Okay, now I have made a piece of code alongside my programming skills developing, so excuse the shoddy coding, and the majority of my code being included, due to me not knowing how to cut it down with it still working and making sense. Any edits to cut it down would be appreciated.

The problem is that my minesweeper game sometimes allows it to hit a mine first round, and I need to make sure this isn't a possibility, it constantly crashes each time I attempt my solution. The idea was that if `self.Counter` was `"start"` and the first clicked one was a mine, it would reset the grid, but it crashed. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


#==================================================================================================
root=Tk()
#==================================================================================================

class GridGame(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.fr=Toplevel(master)
        self.TotalFrame=Frame(self.fr,bg="black")
        self.ButtonColor="red"
        self.GameFrame=Frame(self.TotalFrame,bg="white")
        self.AllButtons=[]
        self.MineGrid=[]
        self.SizeGrid=17
        self.Mines=50
        self.MarkedMineColour="blue"
        self.Counter="Start"
        for x in range(self.SizeGrid):
            Column=[]
            MineColumn=[]
            for y in range(self.SizeGrid):
                item=Button(self.GameFrame,bg=self.ButtonColor,text="",height=2, width=6)
                item.bind("<Button-3>",self.ChoiceChange)
                Column.append(item)
                MineColumn.append("")
            self.AllButtons.append(Column)
            self.MineGrid.append(MineColumn)
        self.GameFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=15,padx=20,columnspan=2)
        self.Quit=Button(self.TotalFrame, text="Destroy This Game", bg="orange",command=self.fr.destroy)
        self.Restart=Button(self.TotalFrame, text="Reset This Game", bg="light blue",command=self.Reset)
        self.Quit.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5,padx=10)
        self.Restart.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,padx=10)
        self.TotalFrame.pack()


        for x in range(self.SizeGrid):
            for y in range(self.SizeGrid):
                    self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(command=lambda a=self.AllButtons[x][y],c=x,d=y:self.ColorFlip(a,c,d))
                    self.AllButtons[x][y].grid(row=x,column=y,padx=5,pady=5)
##        w = self.fr.winfo_screenwidth()
##        h = self.fr.winfo_screenheight()
        self.fr.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (1100, 950, 300, 10))
#==================================================================================================
    def MineGridMaker(self):
        for x in range(0,self.Mines):
                choice1,choice2=random.choice(range(0,len(self.AllButtons))),random.choice(range(0,len(self.AllButtons)))
                if self.MineGrid[choice1][choice2]=="":
                    self.MineGrid[choice1][choice2]="M"
        for x in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
            for y in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="M":
                    for xx in range(x-1,x+2):
                        for yy in range(y-1,y+2):
                            if xx in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and yy in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                                if self.MineGrid[xx][yy]!="M" and self.MineGrid[xx][yy]=="":
                                    self.MineGrid[xx][yy]="1"
                                elif self.MineGrid[xx][yy]!="M" and int(self.MineGrid[xx][yy])>=1:
                                    self.MineGrid[xx][yy]=str(int(self.MineGrid[xx][yy])+1)
#==================================================================================================
    def ColorFlip(self,Object,x,y):
        if self.Counter==self.SizeGrid**2-self.Mines:
            MineGridMaker()
        if Object["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
            if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="M":
                for Item in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                    for item in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                        self.AllButtons[Item][item].configure(bg="grey",text=self.MineGrid[Item][item])
                Object.configure(bg="red",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
                for a in range(x-1,x+2):
                    for b in range(y-1,y+2):
                        if a in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and b in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                            root.after(200,self.BlowUp,a,b)
            else:
                self.Counter-=1
                if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="":
                    for a in range(x-1,x+2):
                        for b in range(y-1,y+2):
                            if a in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and b in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                                if self.AllButtons[a][b]["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
                                    Object.configure(bg="white",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
                                    self.ColorFlip(self.AllButtons[a][b],a,b)
                else:
                    Object.configure(bg="white",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
        if self.Counter<=0:
            for a in range(0,(self.SizeGrid)):
                for b in range(0,(self.SizeGrid)):
                    if self.MineGrid[a][b]=="M":
                        self.AllButtons[a][b].configure(text=self.MineGrid[a][b],bg="orange")
                    else:
                        self.AllButtons[a][b].configure(bg="light green")
#==================================================================================================
    def BlowUp(self,x,y):
        for a in range(1,21):
            root.after((75*a)-25,self.Flash1,x,y)
            root.after(75*a,self.Flash2,x,y)
        root.after(1800,self.Fade,x,y)

    def Flash1(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor:
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="orange")
        except:
            pass

    def Flash2(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor:
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="yellow")
        except:
            pass

    def Fade(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor or self.AllButtons[x][y]["text"]!="":
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="white")
        except:
            pass

    def Reset(self):
        for x in self.AllButtons:
            for y in x:
                y.configure(bg=self.ButtonColor,text="")
        self.Counter=(self.SizeGrid**2)-self.Mines

    def ChoiceChange(self,event):
        if event.widget["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
            event.widget["bg"]=self.MarkedMineColour
        elif event.widget["bg"]==self.MarkedMineColour:
            event.widget["bg"]=self.ButtonColor
```

Comment: By the way, CamelCase for variable names is against PEP8.  You should use something more like `my_variable` instead of `MyVariable`.

Comment: Do you really need all that code to reproduce the problem? Please cut the code down a little, after reading http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry, not the best at cutting it down :/ working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with `self.Counter` being `"Start"`.
When ColourFlip is being called, let it check if `self.Counter` is start, if so, then create the mine grid with the x and y coords being brought in as parameters, and keeping that clicked button as not a mine. Then it should just carry on allowing you to die if there is a mine.

There is the issue of it being reset, it stays the exact same as the last game, so yeah. Might be good, or not.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


#==================================================================================================
root=Tk()
#==================================================================================================

class GridGame(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.fr=Toplevel(master)
        self.TotalFrame=Frame(self.fr,bg="black")
        self.ButtonColor="red"
        self.GameFrame=Frame(self.TotalFrame,bg="white")
        self.AllButtons=[]
        self.MineGrid=[]
        self.SizeGrid=17
        self.Mines=50
        self.MarkedMineColour="blue"
        self.Counter="Start"
        for x in range(self.SizeGrid):
            Column=[]
            MineColumn=[]
            for y in range(self.SizeGrid):
                item=Button(self.GameFrame,bg=self.ButtonColor,text="",height=2, width=6)
                item.bind("<Button-3>",self.ChoiceChange)
                Column.append(item)
                MineColumn.append("")
            self.AllButtons.append(Column)
            self.MineGrid.append(MineColumn)
        self.GameFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=15,padx=20,columnspan=2)
        self.Quit=Button(self.TotalFrame, text="Destroy This Game", bg="orange",command=self.fr.destroy)
        self.Restart=Button(self.TotalFrame, text="Reset This Game", bg="light blue",command=self.Reset)
        self.Quit.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5,padx=10)
        self.Restart.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,padx=10)
        self.TotalFrame.pack()


        for x in range(self.SizeGrid):
            for y in range(self.SizeGrid):
                    self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(command=lambda a=self.AllButtons[x][y],c=x,d=y:self.ColorFlip(a,c,d))
                    self.AllButtons[x][y].grid(row=x,column=y,padx=5,pady=5)
##        w = self.fr.winfo_screenwidth()
##        h = self.fr.winfo_screenheight()
        self.fr.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (1100, 950, 300, 10))
#==================================================================================================
    def MineGridMaker(self,a="a",b="a"):
        for x in range(0,self.Mines):
            CarryOn=False
            while CarryOn==False:
                choice1,choice2=random.choice(range(0,len(self.AllButtons))),random.choice(range(0,len(self.AllButtons)))
                if self.MineGrid[choice1][choice2]=="":
                    if a!=choice1 or b!=choice2:
                        self.MineGrid[choice1][choice2]="M"
                        CarryOn=True

        for x in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
            for y in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="M":
                    for xx in range(x-1,x+2):
                        for yy in range(y-1,y+2):
                            if xx in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and yy in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                                if self.MineGrid[xx][yy]!="M" and self.MineGrid[xx][yy]=="":
                                    self.MineGrid[xx][yy]="1"
                                elif self.MineGrid[xx][yy]!="M" and int(self.MineGrid[xx][yy])>=1:
                                    self.MineGrid[xx][yy]=str(int(self.MineGrid[xx][yy])+1)
#==================================================================================================
    def ColorFlip(self,Object,x,y):
        if self.Counter=="Start":
            self.Counter=(self.SizeGrid**2)-self.Mines
            self.MineGridMaker(x,y)
        if Object["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
            if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="M":
                for Item in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                    for item in range(0,len(self.AllButtons)):
                        self.AllButtons[Item][item].configure(bg="grey",text=self.MineGrid[Item][item])
                Object.configure(bg="red",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
                for a in range(x-1,x+2):
                    for b in range(y-1,y+2):
                        if a in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and b in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                            root.after(200,self.BlowUp,a,b)
            else:
                self.Counter-=1
                if self.MineGrid[x][y]=="":
                    for a in range(x-1,x+2):
                        for b in range(y-1,y+2):
                            if a in range(0,self.SizeGrid) and b in range(0,self.SizeGrid):
                                if self.AllButtons[a][b]["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
                                    Object.configure(bg="white",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
                                    self.ColorFlip(self.AllButtons[a][b],a,b)
                else:
                    Object.configure(bg="white",text=self.MineGrid[x][y])
        if self.Counter<=0:
            for a in range(0,(self.SizeGrid)):
                for b in range(0,(self.SizeGrid)):
                    if self.MineGrid[a][b]=="M":
                        self.AllButtons[a][b].configure(text=self.MineGrid[a][b],bg="orange")
                    else:
                        self.AllButtons[a][b].configure(bg="light green")
#==================================================================================================
    def BlowUp(self,x,y):
        for a in range(1,21):
            root.after((75*a)-25,self.Flash1,x,y)
            root.after(75*a,self.Flash2,x,y)
        root.after(1800,self.Fade,x,y)

    def Flash1(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor:
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="orange")
        except:
            pass

    def Flash2(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor:
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="yellow")
        except:
            pass

    def Fade(self,x,y):
        try:
            if self.AllButtons[x][y]["bg"]!=self.ButtonColor or self.AllButtons[x][y]["text"]!="":
                self.AllButtons[x][y].configure(bg="white")
        except:
            pass

    def Reset(self):
        for x in self.AllButtons:
            for y in x:
                y.configure(bg=self.ButtonColor,text="")
        self.Counter=(self.SizeGrid**2)-self.Mines

    def ChoiceChange(self,event):
        if event.widget["bg"]==self.ButtonColor:
            event.widget["bg"]=self.MarkedMineColour
        elif event.widget["bg"]==self.MarkedMineColour:
            event.widget["bg"]=self.ButtonColor
```

Comment: Thanks! just tested it with 99 mines and 10x10 grid! Works great!